# Dynamic Bar chart scrolling with time using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am fairly new to JavaScript, let alone charting. I'd appreciate any help in accomplishing the following. I have browsed many JavaScript charting libraries and examples but have not seen any that solve my problem:

I need to create dynamic stacked bar charts as shown in the attached picture. Horizontal axis is time axis. The chart should scroll to left with time along with time-markings on x-axis. Each horizontal stacked bar is for a different item on Y-axis. There will be many items on y axis. Each section of bar will have text as shown. The information about each section and its text is received dynamically.

Thank you!

[See the desired end result in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4odXM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Google Charts to be very, very easy to use (https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en)

However, in order to have dynamic content, you'll need to have some data source to read from so that you can use something like `ajax` to constantly ping it for updated data. The Google Charts library will give you a good starting point but it won't be dynamic. You'll have to program that portion but Google Charts is very great in providing you with the basic pie, graph, bar, etc.. 'chart templates' so switching between a bar and a pie chart is super easy.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction of Google Charts. Timeline chart is a great starting option for me. However, I am stuck on how to customize color for each cell. I suspect that the p property may help me with that but I don't know how to use that option to accomplish my goal.